# $x_n$ is any sequence tending to c

Tags: calculus

I'm working on a problem where I have to prove that if $ \lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L $ and $x_n$ is any sequence tending to c, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = L.$

I do not want full proof, but have trouble understanding what "any sequence tending to c" means. Can $\{a_n\}=c$ be called a sequence "tending" to c? How about $\{b_n\}=c$ for all $n>N$, is $b_n$ tending to c?

Regarding the problem, here's what I've been working on:

$\lim_{x→c}f(x)=L⇔∀ε_1>0,∃δ_1>0$ s.t. if $0<|x−c|<δ_1,$ then $|f(x)−L|<ε_1.$

$\lim_{n→∞}x_n=c⇔∀ε_2>0,∃N$ s.t. if $n>N$, then $|x_n−c|<ε_2.$

let $ε_2=\frac{δ_1}{2}$. then $|x_n−c|<\frac{δ_1}{2}<δ_1$ for $n>N.$

then, $∀ε_1>0,∃N$ s.t. if $n>N$, then $|x_n−c|<δ_1$, so $|f(x_n)−L|<ε_1.⇔\lim_{n→∞}f(x_n)=L$

This proof seems incomplete, it seems $0<|x_n−c|$ has to be proven to be complete.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Yes, those are sequences tending to $c$; for all $\epsilon$, there is $N,$ such that if $n>N$, then $|x_n-c|<\epsilon$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the reply. If that's the case, I'm not sure if the statement I'm trying to prove is even true. Say $\{x_n\}=c$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(c) = f(c)$. Since $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ gives no information when $x = c$, it seems we have no way to prove if $f(c) = L$.

Comment: "...it seems we have no way to prove if $f(c)=L.$ " Luckily, you're not trying to prove $f(c)=L.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson we need to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = L$. since $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=f(c)$ when $\{x_n\}=c$, in this case it looks like we need to prove $f(c) = L$.

Comment: Whilst it happens so in that case that $\ f(c) = L,\ $ that is still not the thing you are being asked to prove, even in that case. All you need to do is to go back to the definitions of all the terms you're using, and think about what you're being asked to prove. There is one (epsilon-delta)definition for what is meant by "$ \lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L $" and there is one different (epsilon-$N$) definition for what is meant by, "$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = L.$".

Comment: You should write your attempts to answer the question in the body of your question. This would improve the quality of your question also...

Comment: Understood. Edited the article to write my attempts to solve the problem.